# How to make two onscreenclicks execute after each other

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a problem with the `onscreenclick` function. I have two `onscreenclick` commands in my code and when i press the screen they both exicute at once i want to somehow make it so that the first one executes when I press the screen the first time and the second when I press the second time.

```
import turtle
import time
import random
from random import randint
from time import sleep
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Reaction test")
wn.setup(width=600,  height=600 )
wn.tracer(0)
wn.bgcolor("blue")
turtle.write("Click to start", move=False, align="center", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
from turtle import *
start = time.time()
def clicked(x, y):
    resetscreen()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
    wn.tracer(0)
    wn.bgcolor("red")
    wn.title("Reaction test")
    turtle.write("   Click when the\nscreen turns green", move=False, align="center", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
    sleep(randint(5, 15))
    resetscreen()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
    wn.tracer(0)
    wn.bgcolor("green")
    wn.title("Reaction test")
    turtle.write("CLICK!", move=False, align="center", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
    start
wn.listen()
wn.onscreenclick(clicked)
def click(x, y):
    ms = time.time() - start
    resetscreen()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
    wn.tracer(0)
    wn.bgcolor("Green")
    wn.title("Reaction test")
    milliseconds = int(ms) * 1000
    turtle.write(("Your reaction time was",milliseconds,"milliseconds"), move=False, align="center", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
    wn.listen()
wn.onscreenclick(click)
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `clicked` listener before doing `wn.onscreenclick(click)`

Something like this

```
wn.onscreenclick(None) #remove previous listeners once it's executed.
wn.onscreenclick(click)
```

Comment: Thaks for the response but unfortunatly it doesnt work it still exicutes bothe a the sama time

Answer (score 0):

You can use one handler, keep track of how many clicks have occurred so far and choose your behavior in the handler accordingly. This can get messy with lots of giant conditionals.

Another approach is to only start listening for the second click from the first. Don't forget to remove each listener since they're one-shot.

```
import random
import time
import turtle

def write(msg):
    turtle.write(
        msg, 
        move=False, 
        align="center", 
        font=("Arial", 40, "normal")
    )

class Timer:
    start = 0

def on_first_click(x, y):
    turtle.Screen().onscreenclick(None)
    turtle.resetscreen()
    turtle.Screen().bgcolor("red")
    write("   Click when the\nscreen turns green")
    time.sleep(random.randint(5, 15))
    turtle.resetscreen()
    turtle.Screen().bgcolor("green")
    Timer.start = time.time()
    write("CLICK!")
    turtle.Screen().onscreenclick(on_second_click)

def on_second_click(x, y):
    turtle.Screen().onscreenclick(None)
    elapsed_ms = round((time.time() - Timer.start) * 1000, 3)
    turtle.resetscreen()
    write(f"Your reaction time was\n{elapsed_ms} milliseconds")
    turtle.exitonclick()

turtle.hideturtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Reaction test")
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)
wn.bgcolor("blue")
write("Click to start")
wn.onscreenclick(on_first_click)
wn.mainloop()
```

I removed the `from turtle import *` which pollutes the global namespace and makes the code hard to understand. When you prefix everything with `turtle`, it's easy to tell what's a turtle library function and what's part of your code.

Using a global is poor practice because shared state tends to lead to bugs that are confusing to unravel, so I use `class Timer: timer = 0` to namespace the state that needs to be shared between click handlers.

The version above isn't thread safe and is rather single-use. If you want to run this in a loop, here's a decent next-step refactor:

```
import random
import time
import turtle

def write(msg):
    turtle.write(
        msg, 
        move=False, 
        align="center", 
        font=("Arial", 40, "normal")
    )

class Reaction:
    def __init__(self, turtle):
        self.turtle = turtle
        self.start_time = 0

    def on_first_click(self, x, y):
        self.turtle.Screen().onscreenclick(None)
        self.turtle.resetscreen()
        self.turtle.Screen().bgcolor("red")
        write("   Click when the\nscreen turns green")
        time.sleep(random.randint(5, 15))
        self.turtle.resetscreen()
        self.turtle.Screen().bgcolor("green")
        self.start = time.time()
        write("CLICK!")
        self.turtle.Screen().onscreenclick(self.on_second_click)

    def on_second_click(self, x, y):
        self.turtle.Screen().onscreenclick(None)
        elapsed_ms = round((time.time() - self.start) * 1000, 3)
        self.turtle.resetscreen()
        write(f"Your reaction time was\n{elapsed_ms} milliseconds")
        self.turtle.exitonclick()

    def run(self):
        self.start = 0
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        wn = self.turtle.Screen()
        wn.title("Reaction test")
        wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
        wn.tracer(0)
        wn.bgcolor("blue")
        write("Click to start")
        wn.onscreenclick(self.on_first_click)
        wn.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Reaction(turtle).run()
```

Comment: Thx realy helped appriciate it

Answer (score 0):

Use a global click counter.  Then decide what your turtle does during your click routine from there.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from random import randint
import time
import turtle as tr

turtle, screen  = tr .Turtle(),  tr .Screen()
screen .setup( width=640,  height=480 )
screen .title( 'Reaction test' )
screen .bgcolor( 'blue' )
screen .tracer( 5, 0 )
turtle .hideturtle()
turtle .penup()
screen .update()

C= 'center'
smallfont = ( 'Arial', 33, 'normal' )
largefont = ( 'Arial', 44, 'normal' )
turtle .write( 'Click to start', align=C, font=largefont )
clicks, start = 0, 0  ##  empty forward declarations

def clicked(x, y):  ##  just use one click callback
    global clicks, start
    if clicks == 0:
        turtle .clear()
        screen .bgcolor( 'red' )
        turtle .write( '   Click when the\nscreen turns green', align=C, font=largefont )
        screen .update()
        time .sleep( randint(3, 5) )
        turtle .clear()
        screen .bgcolor( 'green' )
        turtle .write( 'CLICK!', align=C, font=largefont )
        screen .update()
        start = time .time()
        clicks += 1
    elif clicks == 1:
        now = time .time()
        turtle .clear()
        ms = round( (now -start) *1000,  3 )
        turtle .write( f'Your reaction time was\n  {ms} milliseconds', align=C, font=smallfont )
        screen .update()
        time .sleep( 2.5 )
        turtle .goto( 0, 100 )
        turtle .write( 'Thanks', align=C, font=largefont )
        time .sleep( 1.5 )
        screen .bye()

screen .listen()
screen .onscreenclick( clicked )
screen .mainloop()
```